# Quadratic form upper bound for arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the form $ \frac{x^T B x}{x^T x}  $ I am asked to find a constant $C$ such that $\frac{x^T B x}{x^T x} \le C \lambda (B)$
where $\lambda(B)$ is the largest eigenvalue of $B$, or prove no such constant exists. I am also given the following assumptions about $B$, but I think 1 and 2 are not necessary

1. $B$ is a 2x2 matrix
2. $B$ is a real matrix
3. $B$ has real eigenvalues
4. $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$

We can decompose $B$ into symmetric $S$ and antisymmetric parts giving $\frac{x^T B x}{x^T x}=\frac{x^T S x}{x^Tx}$
and now diagonalise $S$, the following result then comes easily
$$\frac{x^T S x}{x^Tx}\le \lambda(S)$$

Then all I need is $\lambda(S)\le\lambda(B)$ but I have no idea if this is true or not. It is mentioned in the comments of the downvoted answer on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795563/lower-bound-on-quadratic-form) post that it is true, but when the author was asked for a proof, he disappeared.
I would like to know

1. Am I overcomplicating this problem and theres just another way to do it?

Or 2. Is this inequality true and I've done it right?

Comment: hint: consider non-zero nilpotent $B$

Comment: @user8675309 nil what?

Comment: [This is the Wiki entry on nilpotent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix).